# Bar Button Item in Navigation Bar is not Visible - Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I know thr are many questions on this topic bt none of the solutions seemed to work.

I want to implement a "back button" on my present view i.e DetailViewController which when pressed will load the initial view controller.

So in the navigation bar of this DetailViewController, i hv added a Bar Button Item, and have given it the IBAction as shown below:

```
@IBAction func backToCenter(sender: AnyObject) {
  self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController()
}
```

But when i open the detail view, the back button does not appear

[image]

I dont think there is a space issue as mentioned in one of the answers of similar question where items are arranged right to left and if there isnt enough space available, then they are not visible.

Cutting the story short, Pls help me get the Back button on the DetailViewController..

**Update:**

I already have a navigatorcontroller between my TableView and DetailView Controllers:

See the snap of my storyboard:

[image]

Comment: The Back button is automatically provided by the system. Have you read the [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)?

Comment: You normally don't need to do anything to get a back button when using a navigation controller and following a push segue. Remove the back button that you added manually.

Comment: @jtbandes thanks for adding the image :) but as you can see in the screenshot there is no back button in the simulator

Comment: @Jafar i did not want to put the back button.. but i want to navigate back to the UITableView from where my segue DetailViewController was opened. So i added it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the Navigationcontroller before your TableViewController and not after your controller. That way your back button will work.

Like that:

```
Start-TableViewcontroller -> NavigationController -> Second Tableviewcontroller -> Viewcontroller
```

Comment: I have already embedded the Navigation Controller. Check the updated question. Hv attached the snap of my storyboard

Comment: Put the navigationcontroller at the start as rootviewcontroller and connect it with your first tableviewcontroller. that should work. I've updated my answer.

Comment: i made a new project from scratch and then everthing worked well. putting NavigaionController before TableView Controller was the required thing. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Same problem solved by change Segue to "Show Detail"

Comment: I mean Segue to TabBarController